# How do I generate permutations of length LEN given a list of N Items?

Tags: python, permutation

Note: I'm working in python on this.

For example, given a list:

```
list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
```

I want to generate a list of lists with all possible 3-item combinations:

```
['a','b','c'],
['a','b','d'],
['a','b','e']
```

The permutations should not use the same item twice in a permutation, but the order is important and represents distinct permutations that should be included, e.g.,

```
['a','b','c'],
['a','c','b']
```

Should both be included.

"3" is the magic length for the permutations I'm looking to generate, but I wouldn't look down on a solution for arbitrary length permutations.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you thought about the problem at all? Is there a point where you're getting stuck?

Comment: I hate to say it, but googling "permutations python list" gave http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html.

Comment: Someone else answered already, but yeah, I'd given it some thought, but after other aspects of the project to which this is related, I've gone into brain lock and couldn't think past a brute force method with lots of ugliness.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
itertools.permutations(my_list, 3)
```

Answer (score 18):

Assuming you're in python 2.6 or newer:

```
from itertools import permutations
for i in permutations(your_list, 3):
    print i
```

Answer (score 13):

In case you need all combinations of a list with length n where n may be larger than the list elements, and also with repeated elements:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.product([-1,1], repeat=3))
```

[(-1, -1, -1), (-1, -1, 1), (-1, 1, -1), (-1, 1, 1), (1, -1, -1), (1, -1, 1), (1, 1, -1), (1, 1, 1)]

imagine a cartesian product like [-1,1]x[-1,1]x[-1,1]

Answer (score 4):

You should use the [`permutations`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) function from the `itertools` module.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> lst = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
>>> itertools.permutations(lst, 3)
```

Or, if you really want to get combinations, then use the [`combinations`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) function.