# All lists where each element can change from 0 to a

Tags: python

Assume we are given two positive integers a and b. We want to know all possible all possible lists of size b where each element can be from 0 to a (not including a).

For example if a =2, b=2, we should have [0,0],[0,1], [1,0],[1,1].

Is there any way for having all such lists with Standard python functions?

Comment: With itertools this is a snap. Does that count as standard python?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338052/how-do-i-generate-permutations-of-length-len-given-a-list-of-n-items

Comment: @JohnColeman Preferably, without itertools.

Comment: You can roll your own recursive solution, but it is literally 1-line with itertools: `[list(p) for p in itertools.product(range(a),repeat=b)]`